# Able to create, but can not update

Tags: ruby, mongoid

It could create, but can not update.
**main.rb**

```
post '/create' do
  o = Organization.new(
  title: params[:organization][:title],
  body: params[:organization][:body],
  location: [params[:organization][:longtitude], params[:organization][:latitude]]
   )
  if o.save
    redirect '/'
  else
    flash[:error] = "Error saving a organization document."
  end
end

get '/edit/:id' do |id|
  @o = Organization.find(id)
  slim :edit
end

put '/update/:id' do
  @o = Organization.find(params[:id])
  @o.update_attributes(title: params[:organization][:title],
  body: params[:organization][:body],
  location: [params[:organization][:longtitude], params[:organization] [:latitude]])
  slim :show
end
```

**edit.slim**

```
h2 Edit

form#organizationForm action="/update/#{@o.id}" method="POST"
  input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"
  |title
  input type="text" name="organization[title]" value="#{@o.title}"
  |body
  input type="text" name="organization[body]" value="#{@o.body}"
  |longtitude
  input type="text" name="organization[longtitude]" value="#{@o.location[0]}"
  |latitude
  input type="text" name="organization[latitude]" value="#{@o.location[1]}"
  input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"
```

**organization.rb**

```
class Organization
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Geospatial
  field :title,    type: String
  field :body,     type: String

  # define fields
  field :location, type: Point, spatial: true
  field :route,    type: LineString
  field :area,     type: Polygon
  field :around,   type: Circle
end
```

Error messgage,

> Mongoid::Errors::UnknownAttribute at /update/55a6781373696454b5000000
>   Problem: Attempted to set a value for 'longtitude' which is not allowed on the model Organization. Summary: Without including Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic in your model and the attribute does not already exist in the attributes hash, attempting to call Organization#longtitude= for it is not allowed. This is also triggered by passing the attribute to any method that accepts an attributes hash, and is raised instead of getting a NoMethodError. Resolution: You can include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic if you expect to be writing values for undefined fields often.
>   file: processing.rb location: process_attribute line: 96

I think no need to include `Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic`, because could create.

Comment: Sorry not really up much on using slim, but shouldnt those form fields both be "organization[location]"? That's how you would normally handle an array in a standard form post.

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven, yes can handle it as an array, but I would like to separate input form.  by the way, when I run this program again, no error. sorry for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just I forgot run again this progrm after change main.rb code.
The code is okay.